# Plotly: How to plot markers with time values on a different trace?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have 2 data frames:
df1 contains columns: “time”, “bid_price”
df2 contains columns: “time”, “flag”

I want to plot a time series of df1 as a line graph and i want to put markers on that trace at points where df2 “flag” column value = True at those points in time

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so in three steps:

1. set up a figure using `go.Figure()`,
2. add a trace for your bid_prices using `fig.update(go.Scatter)`
3. and do the same thing for your flags.

The snippet below does exactly what you're describing in your question. I've set up two dataframes `df1` and `df2`, and then I've merged them together to make things a bit easier to reference later on.
I'm also showing flags for an accumulated series where each `increment in the series > 0.9` is flagged in `flags = [True if elem > 0.9 else False for elem in bid_price]` . You should be able to easily adjust this to whatever your real world dataset looks like.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code with random data:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# settings
observations = 100
np.random.seed(5); cols = list('a')
bid_price = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=observations).tolist()
flags = [True if elem > 0.9 else False for elem in bid_price]
time = [t for t in pd.date_range('2020', freq='D', periods=observations).format()]


# bid price
df1=pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 
                 'bid_price':bid_price})
df1.set_index('time',inplace = True)
df1.iloc[0]=0; d1f=df1.cumsum()

# flags
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 
                 'flags':flags})
df2.set_index('time',inplace = True)

df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df.bid_price = df.bid_price.cumsum()
df['flagged'] = np.where(df['flags']==True, df['bid_price'], np.nan)

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# trace for bid_prices
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['bid_price'], mode = 'lines',
                         name='bid_price'))

# trace for flags
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['flagged'], mode = 'markers',
              marker =dict(symbol='triangle-down', size = 16),
              name='Flag'))
               
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Hey mate.  Upvote for the data synthesis / engineering.  Learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @S3DEV My pleasure! There are certainly more elegant ways to do the same things though. Using `time = [t for t in pd.date_range('2020', freq='D', periods=observations).format()]` isn't very brief or efficient. But I didn't bother looking up anything else right now.